Conditionally remove shift xkb modifier
I have successfully created a xkb configuration for a custom keyboard layout. However, one thing I cannot achieve is set up another key with “Home” behavior. I’d like that other key to work like the original “HOME” key, including when Shift is pressed together with Home (select everything between current and start).
Here is an extract from one of my attempts.
default partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "myconfig" {
  name[Group1]= "namegroup";
  include "latin"
  key <AB09> { [ Home, Home, NoSymbol, NoSymbol ] };
};

Pressing the key alone makes it act as a Home key, as desired, but pressing it together with Shift makes it act as if I was just pressing the Home key without Shift (so it does not select anything).
Indeed, when using xkbcli interactive-wayland, I can see how this new key I am configuring differs from the original HOME key. Pressing Shift together with the original HOME key yields seat0: keysyms [ Home             ] unicode [  ] layout [ namegroup (0) ] level [ 0 ] mods [ Shift ] leds [ ] while pressing Shift together with the new key (“AB09”) yields seat0: keysyms [ Home             ] unicode [  ] layout [ namegroup (0) ] level [ 1 ] mods [ -Shift ] leds [ ]. This, I suppose, shows that the Shift modifier is removed before reaching the application, which thus has no chance to act according to my holding Shift. By contrast, note that pressing Shift together with a letter (under a default xkb layout such as “fr”) does remove the Shift modifier, as expected, so there seems to be by default a special treatment for keys such as HOME in xkb. I ignore where and how this is specified.
I have seen some posts about the “preserve” keyword or the redirect actions, but this seems to pre-date Wayland.
Does anyone know how to make AB09 behave as the (default behavior of the) HOME key?
Alternatively, does anyone know where the behavior of the original HOME key is configured? I cannot find any place under the usual xkb configuration files directory (/usr/share/X11/xkb/) that indicates special treatment of this key (or the arrow keys which behave similarly), by comparison to any other key such as the letter keys. Copying such special configuration would probably solve my problem.
